# mySQL select random with probability

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I've got a database table with an integer field - call it "flavour", and the values of that field can only be the numbers 1 to 10.

Is there a way to select a single random row from the database, with a 20% chance it will be flavour six, a 30% chance it will be flavour two, and a 50% chance it will be flavour one?

---

Apologies for the late response - many thanks for the help. Eugen's answer seems to best encompass what I need; I'm aware of the dangers of ORDER BY rand(), but the application I'm writing won't operate on a large data source, or have to support many concurrent users. So I'll go with it and accept the performance hit.

Comment: One way to handle the weights would be to have the number of rows with the data for a "flavour" match their respective weight. Eg. a 30% chance gets 3 rows out of 10. Not a clean way, but might be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT
  IF(@rnd<0.5,1,IF(@rnd<0.8,2,6)) AS rndflavour
FROM
  (SELECT @rnd:=rand()) AS rndinit;
```

Gives you the flavour with the requested probabilities.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

gives you a single random row. Now we put it together:

```
SELECT
  tablename.*
FROM
  tablename
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      IF(@rnd<0.5,1,IF(@rnd<0.8,2,6)) AS rndflavour
    FROM
      (SELECT @rnd:=rand()) AS rndinit
  ) AS rndview ON rndview.rndflavour=tablename.flavour
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If your table is large, I’d recommend strongly against `ORDER BY rand()` — this will result in very poor performance.

Comment: Only the part with the pre-chosen flavour will be ordered by rand() - this mitigates you very valid performance concerns

Comment: You don't need `ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1` at the end.

Comment: I beg to disagree: Else you will get the correct flavour, but a non-random member of that flavour

Answer (score 0):

I suggest do divide the task

1 
   write some logic that assigns a value to variable :your_flavour with appropriate chances

2

```
select * from YOUR_TABLE where FLAVOUR = :your_flavour order by rand() limit 1
```